# Rails 4: how can I DRY out my multiple form partials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My app has objects Foo and Bar, which each have corresponding models, views and controllers.

A form partial comes standard after generating scaffolding for each object.

Foo form partial looks something like...

```
<div class="form-inputs row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= Foo.donut %>
    <%= Foo.bagel %>
    <%= Foo.cookie %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-inputs row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= Foo.biscuit %>
    <%= Foo.toast %>
    <%= Foo.muffin %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Bar form partial looks something like...

```
<div class="form-inputs row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= Bar.cat %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-inputs row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= Bar.dog %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want uniform formatting and I want it to be easy to maintain, but the objects have different attributes and different numbers of attributes. Is there a way for me to DRY out my formatting?

Comment: What do you mean by 'formatting', exactly?

Comment: Both Foo and Bar form partials in my example intentionally use the same div structure and Twitter Bootstrap classes. Ideally, I'd like this look-and-feel to persist throughout the application without maintaining several form partials that are all **almost exactly** the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a repeating structure for rendering you could extract that into a partial and then pass the variables for rendering. So your partial looks like

```
<div class="form-inputs row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <% vals.each do |val|   %>
    <%= val %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in your main view you pass the variables for rendering.

```
<%= render 'home', vals: [Foo.biscuit, Foo.bagel] %>
```

Comment: Also you can reduce the amount of visible markup by using an abstraction markup language like HAML. I'm not too familiar with frontend in rails so there may be a better way.